# In PostgreSQL why does command line window disappear when I press Enter after entering my password?

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-prompt

I installed PostgreSQL on my laptop today (running Windows 10) and I am trying to get started learning SQL. The PostgreSQL Installation Tutorial said to try connecting using command prompt, by opening psql.exe, so I did that, got the command window, and it asked me for my password. I entered that and pressed the Enter key -- and the window disappeared. Multiple times. The password is definitely correct.

What did I do wrong? I've looked hard for info about this but have not found answers. I'm just trying to be sure my setup is correct and ready to go.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you using `cmd` or just start `psql.exe`?

Comment: I just started psql.exe and then the command window opened and asked me for my password.

Comment: And then, if something wrong, `psql` have closed and command window disappeared. That what you have for now. Start `cmd` (or powershell) first and in its command window start `psql`.

Comment: OK, I just did that, and the same thing happened: The psql.exe file opened a new command prompt window, asked for my password, then closed the window when I entered it.

Comment: Step by step: Press `[Win]+[R]`, type `cmd`, press `[Enter]`, in the window that opened type `psql`, press `[Enter]`. Is it what you doing?

Comment: Not quite - but I just tried it as you describe above, and typing `psql` was not recognized as a command. So then I entered `start C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe` and that opened a separate command prompt window. In that window I was prompted for a password, and when I pressed Enter the window closed.

Comment: Do not use `start`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! That worked. And I also had to switch users to make the authentication work, so I need to fix that. But I'll work on that myself before asking for help. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and the reason is by default the SQL connection uses windows username(the user with which you are logged in) while this user is not created on the DB.

Use the following command while login: 
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>psql.exe -d postgres -U postgres