# postgres 13, terminal(psql) closes after asking for password

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've just installed postgres 13 and am trying to learn it for the first time. (windows) During the installation process I was prompted to create a password.

Now when I try to open up the psql terminal I'm immediately prompted enter a password.

After I enter the password the terminal just closes for some reason and nothing further happens.

From what I gather on-line, some are saying this is due to postgres using my 'windows user login' as it's user?

I'm not sure what the fix is for this or how to go about using postgres from here.

Does anyone have any insight?
Explain it to me like I'm 5 please.

Comment: Weird.  What terminal program are you using?  What version of Windows?  What installer did you use to install PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have windows 10 - 

I've just gone to the postgresql website and followed the download links to get the latest version of postgres  - 13.1

After this install I was attempting to connect via the terminal that came with the install,  psql

Comment: So you are just double-clicking on psql.exe from within the file browser GUI?  In that case, it is just closing the window before you can read what the error message is.  I would start a real terminal first, like `cmd` from Run menu, then launch psql from the command line.

Comment: This was the issue, I was receiving an error about the password being wrong.   The reason is it was attempting to log in my windows user and that user doesn't exist. 

Between what you said and an answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021440/in-postgresql-why-does-command-line-window-disappear-when-i-press-enter-after-en

I was able to log in,  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As talked about in the comments, the solution was to open psql.exe from cmd.
The reason the terminal was closing was due to a password Auth error.

From there I was able to call the .exe with the appropriate options.
eg
psql.exe -d postgres -U postgres

I found that from this answer:
[In PostgreSQL why does command line window disappear when I press Enter after entering my password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021440/in-postgresql-why-does-command-line-window-disappear-when-i-press-enter-after-en)

The problem was that the shell will by default try and use the windows user as the log in ID, and the password you type will be incorrect for that log in ID.